# image thumbnails of carousel in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I have a carousel in angular 4 and I am using ng-bootstrap. I want to make change the indicators and make them thumbnail images like [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/article-carousel-with-images-indicators)

Here is my current ngb code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ngb-carousel>
            <ng-template ngbSlide>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500 r=1" alt="Random first slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>First slide label</h3>
                    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbSlide>
                <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" alt="Random second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbSlide>
                <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" alt="Random third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                    <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Old Answer**

I came across your question when searching for similar feature. Unfortunately, we are not able to customize the `carousel-indicator` as the time of this post. You can look at the the issue opened [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1587).

If we dive into the source code, there is no dynamic templating in the `li` here [in this line](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts#L49).

**New Answer**

I've come up with workaround for this. Upon inspection on the `ng-bootstrap` [source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts) and [api documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api), you can see that `ngb-carousel` accept `activeId` input. So, we can create a method that will pass the clicked photo thumbnail to the `ngb-carousel`.

The most important part is:

1. Put the input properties `[activeId]` inside `ngb-carousel`

   `<ngb-carousel class="myCarousel" [activeId]="activeSliderId"></ngb-carousel>`
2. Create a click event when clicking the thumbnail

   `<li class="thumbnail" (click)="cycleToSlide(photo)"></li>`
3. Method to call upon clicking the thumbnail

   ```js
    cycleToSlide(photo) {
      this.activeSliderId = "ngb-slide-" + photo.id;
    }
   ```

You can see the example below.

```js
export class PhotosComponent {
  activeSliderId;

  cycleToSlide(photo) {
    console.log(photo.id - 1);
    let slideId = photo.id - 1;

    this.activeSliderId = "ngb-slide-" + slideId;
  }

}
```

```css
.carousel-thumbnail {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1rem 0 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-thumbnail__item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-thumbnail__img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ngb-carousel class="myCarousel" [activeId]="activeSliderId">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of photos">
    <img class="slide__image" [src]="photo.src" alt="Random {{photo.name}} slide">
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>

<ul class="carousel-thumbnail">
  <li class="carousel-thumbnail__item list-inline-item" *ngFor="let photo of photos" (click)="cycleToSlide(photo)">
    <a class="selected">
      <img class="carousel-thumbnail__img" [src]="photo.src">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```